Is there a way to delete all my SE accounts and to never visit you again?
I am sorry to say this, but I suffered plenty of tears, grief, sorrow and misunderstanding. English is not my first language in any way. So is there a way to delete all my SE accounts and somehow not to visit you ever again? I am sorry, I tried not to do any harm; I just wanted to speak to people who will support me instead of criticizing me... Maybe I am too prejudiced. I think deleting all my SE accounts would bring peace and happiness to my existence.

I'm sorry that you feel you were criticised and not supported. I'm sure it wasn't intentional.

I'm sorry your experience here brought you pain and I hope you find the support you're looking for. I hope it isn't seen as further criticism that I'll flag this question to be moved to the "Meta" section, where we ask about the site itself as opposed to about language. Also, without any unfriendliness intended, I'll suggest that "not visiting again" is easy and requires no extra steps.

I'm sorry to hear that you've been going through such a difficult time. It's understandable to feel overwhelmed and discouraged, especially when language barriers can make communication challenging. Your feelings are valid, and I want to assure you that I understand why you might want to take a break from Stack Exchange.
If you feel that deleting your accounts would bring you peace and happiness, then that's a decision only you can make. I respect your choice and wish you all the best. Please know that you're not alone in your feelings, and there are many people who care about their own well-being.
Here is the link that can help you:
You can do the same on the other sites as well. Just go to the sandwich bar on the top right and click "help". You will see "How do I delete my account?" there.
https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account
